# UITableViewCell and setting subview frames in layoutSubviews doesn't work first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a prototype UITableViewCell subclass in a storyboard that uses auto layout (but the cell itself doesn't have any elements using auto layout). I'm trying to set the frame of a subview manually in it's layoutSubviews method but this only works when the cell is reused, or is highlighted. The first time the cell is displayed, setting subview frames doesn't have an effect (but the method is called and setting background colours and stuff works fine). Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: Ok I was wrong about the behaviour, it seems as though when reusing cells the subviews frames get reset again.

Comment: Are you calling `setNeedsLayout` after setting up your frames?

Comment: On the subviews that I'm editing? Yep, tried that.

Comment: Does `layoutIfNeeded` work?

Comment: Calling layoutIfNeeded stops the subviews from laying out at all (even when the cell is selected). Also just edited my question as I was wrong about the behaviour.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the cell selected in interface builder with the object browser open?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the cell to call layoutSubviews maybe you need to use setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded in awakeFromNib.